# Can inserting a shim fix a misaligned nozzle assembly on an Ender 3 S1 Plus?

Tags: creality-ender-3, diy-3d-printer

I recently purchased an Ender 3 S1 Plus. Printed off the benchy, went great, tried a more complex print with a 0.16 mm height, and it looks wonderful. However, when I tried to print something a bit taller (~200 mm), the nozzle assembly (I believe the fan is the culprit) started catching on the print and in one instance got stuck and burned in a small divot.

I've leveled the X-gantry to the bed and checked the assembly angle. It still appears to be off, and I'm wondering if I should insert a shim where it screws in, to fix the angle.

[image: Photo of nozzle assembly at an angle compared to the bed]

[image: Photo of a partial print on a ender 3 s1 plus printer]

Comment: It is close, but overall higher positioned than the nozzle, it should not catch on your print at all. Can you print a cylinder of the same height to reproduce the problem? You may take some pictures of that.

Comment: Hey Oscar,  I added a picture of the piece that was catching the most.  There would occasionally be a very loud POP as it went over the tree support.  it only really happened towards the left side of the print.


I believe the issue is that the mounting bracket itself is bent.  If i could somehow get that back into alignment, the whole issue would be solved.

Comment: The back left is the problem, somehow it accumulated a chunk of molten filament, could indicate that retraction is a bit under par.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment.  I'm trying my best to see any chunks of filament but i seem to be missing it.  the print was catching on everything from the middle of the print to the left.  At times I could hear the sound of it moving over the infill like a bicycle with cards in the spokes.